# Ruby on Rails: Form routes to a different URL

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2, polymorphic-associations

I have a form that saves data, but it gets routed to the wrong URL.

If my form is in

> localhost:3000/users/1/styles/1

And when I submit the form, I get redirected to this:

> localhost:3000/styles/1

and then I get an error:

> Couldn't find User without an ID

**views/comments/_form.html.erb**

```
<%= form_for [@commentable, @comment] do |f| %>
  <%= f.text_area :content, rows: 3 %>
  <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>
```

**styles_controller.rb**

```
def show
  @user = User.find(params[:user_id])
  @style = @user.styles.find(params[:id])
  @commentable = @style
  @comments = @commentable.comments
  @comment = Comment.new
end
```

**comments_controller.rb**

```
before_filter :get_commentable

def new
  @comment = @commentable.comments.new
end

def create
  @comment = @commentable.comments.new(params[:comment])
  @comment.user = current_user
  if @comment.save
    redirect_to @commentable, notice: "Comment created."
  else
    render :new
  end
end

private
def get_commentable
  @commentable = params[:commentable].classify.constantize.find(commentable_id)
end

def commentable_id
  params[(params[:commentable].singularize + "_id").to_sym]
end
```

**routes.rb**

```
resources :styles do
  resources :comments, :defaults => { :commentable => 'style' }
end
```

Please let me know if there's other information that is needed. Why am I getting rerouted to a different url? My comment does save into my database.

Thank you

Comment: When you look at the Form HTML in your browser's View Source, do you see the correct URL? (I assume it is not, but just asking since you said it gets 'redirected' to wrong URL)

Comment: @RajeshKolappakam yeah, `action="/styles/1/comments"` what is rails best practice to getting this correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to go back to `localhost:3000/users/1/styles/1` after creating comment, you should change

```
  if @comment.save
    redirect_to @commentable, notice: "Comment created."
  else
```

to

```
  if @comment.save
    redirect_to [User.find(params[:user_id]), @commentable], notice: "Comment created."
  else
```

Edit: Should use User that owns the style not current user

Comment: I'm trying to get the current id, not the logged in id which `current_user` is. It will just redirect it to the person that is commenting. I tried `params[:user_id]` but its not correct, this helps me, but how do i retain the id of the current URL that I'm commenting?

Comment: Just use User.find(params[:user_id])